# Show that $G/N$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{*} \times \mathbb{R}^{*}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I want to solve the following:

> Let $G$ be the multiplicative group of elements of the form 
>   $$
>     \begin{pmatrix}
>     a & b \\
>     0 & c \\
>     \end{pmatrix}
> $$ where $a\neq 0, c\neq0$, $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$.
>   Let $N$ be a subgroup of $G$ that consists of elements of the form 
>   $$
>     \begin{pmatrix}
>     1 & b \\
>     0 & 1 \\
>     \end{pmatrix}.
> $$
>
> Show that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and prove that $G/N$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{*} \times \mathbb{R}^{*}$.

I have managed to show the part about $N$ being a normal subgroup. But I'm stuck on the second part.

My initial idea was to use the first isomorphism theorem, and find a surjective homomorphism $f: G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{*} \times \mathbb{R}^{*} $ with kernel $N$. I believe we then have to consider $\mathbb{R}^{*} \times \mathbb{R}^{*}$ an additive group, otherwise we'll never have $f(A*B) = f(A)*f(B)$, since $f(A*B)$ will be an element of the form $(a,b)$ and $f(A)*f(B)$ will be a scalar.

But I haven't been able to "construct" such a homomorphic function $f$, so if anyone has any ideas I would be greatful.

Comment: just a small caveat: $(\mathbb{R}^\times,+)$ is not a group

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $f:G\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^*\times\mathbb{R}^*$ defined by $f\left(\matrix{a&b\cr 0&c}\right)=(a,c)$ show that $f$ is an epimorphism and its kernel is $N$.

$\mathbb{R}^*\times\mathbb{R}^*$ is the multiplicative group.

Comment: To see how one might consider this in the first place, look at the generic element of $N$ and consider the fact that this ought to be sent to $(1, 1)$. What's the easiest (non-trivial) way to do that? Well, it's this one.

Comment: An epimorphism is a surjective homomorphism, right? The first thing I did was trying using $f$ defined as above. But then I don't get $f(A*B) = f(A)*f(B)$... Because $f(A)*f(B)$ would be the product of two vectors $(a,b)$ and $(a',b')$ which is impossible (right?) because of the dimensions.

Comment: @virreand Maybe you're not entirely clear on what the standard product on $\Bbb R^*\times \Bbb R^*$ is. It's $(a, b)(c, d) = (ac, bd)$ (that's how $\times$ works when in the context of groups). There is nothing here that has anything to do with vectors.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't. I didn't know it was the standard but I just figured out that I may define the group operation on $\mathbb{R}^{*} \times \mathbb{R}^{*}$ like that since it satisfies the necessary axioms. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd consider the mapping $G\rightarrow {\Bbb R}^*\times {\Bbb R}^*$ defined by
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b\\ 0 &c\end{array}\right)\mapsto (a,c).$$